# Android Studio does not show anchor points when laying out a custom component in a ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, custom-controls, kotlin-android-extensions

I've developed a super simple custom View in Android, to be used as a generic placeholder, that just shows a diagonal line between the upper-left vertex to the lower-right one.

The problem is that when I try to lay out it in a ConstraintLayout, the editor does not show the anchor point I would expect. An image is worth a thousand words:

[image]

If you're experienced with Android Studio you know that if I were using a standard View, like a Button, instead of mine custom View, the green arrow should normally hook to the grey "BUTTON", representing a vertical constraint.

Any idea why Android Studio does not behave as expected ? 
It is an Android Studio bug or maybe my custom view misses something else like some callback method ?

It is worth to mention than if I manually edit the layout XML writing the proper contraints and then I reopen the view, it is shown correctly, with all the arrows representing contraints in place! Even the one that I was not able to draw in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the answer was quite easy. In order to properly work, it is mandatory to assign an `android:id` to all components. If some components involved in a `ConstraintLayout` do not have it, it is impossible for Android Studio to set such constraint. This is because a constraint has this kind of form:

```
app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="<ID OF THE COMPONENT ATTACHED TO>"
```

So... in my case it was enough to ensure all components, be them custom or default ones, have an ID.